# Summing rows of a table in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-lists, nested-for-loop

I'm trying to create a function that takes a table and returns a list containing the sum of each row.
E.g.  `func([[0.2,0.1],[-0.2,0.1],[0.2,-0.1],[-0.2,-0.1]])` returns `[0.3, -0.1, 0.1, -0.3]`.

I know that the table is a 2D nested list, that each row contains only numbers and that each row is the same length.

I've got this code, but it seems to just return the last number in the list. Something is broken with the accumulators but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

```py
num_rows = len(table)
num_columns = len(table[0])
result = []

for m in range(num_columns):
    row = []
    for n in range(num_rows):
        row.append(table[n][m])
        row = sum(row)

result.append(row)

return result
```

Comment: There are multiple things wrong with your code that will become apparent with some debugging.  Most glaring is that you append to the result only once, _after your loop ends_. You also set `row=sum(row)` in the first iteration of the inner loop, so now it is no longer a list and cannot be appended to in the next iteration of the inner loop. See https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

You must iterate each row and append sum of the row to your result list

```
#table is for example n*m n row
result=[]
for row in table:#  from 0 row to nth row        
    result.append(sum(row))
```

Answer (score 0):

If This is a very simple thing to do with a list comprehension:

```py
def func(lst):
    return [sum(row) for row in lst]
```

Or it's equivalent `map()` approach:

```py
def func(lst):
    return list(map(sum, lst))
```

**Note**: In pure Python it's sufficient but if you need fast operations on multi-dimension arrays, consider using [Numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/index.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

A simple nested for loop will do. List comprehension will also work but I personally dislike it.

```
result = []

for row in table:
    sum_of_each_row = 0

    for value in row:
        sum_of_each_row += value

    result.append(sum_of_each_row)
```

Output:

```
[0.30000000000000004, -0.1, 0.1, -0.30000000000000004]
```

Basically, we are looping through every row in the table and then looping through every value of the row. Added up the values and `append()` it to the result list.

Note: The reason why it is returning **0.30000000000000004** is because of a simple rounding problem in python.